# Text in JSX has the type 'string', but the expected type of 'children' is 'string | Element | Element[]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a custom React button component that I want to be able to take optional strings with or without optional icons (`JSX.Element`) as cildren.

My interface looks like this

```
interface IUploadFileButtonProps {
  children: string | JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}
```

And the implementation:

```
// Does not work
<UploadFileButton>
  <FaUpload />
  Add new list
</UploadFileButton>

// Works
<UploadFileButton>
  No icon, just text
</UploadFileButton>

// Works
<UploadFileButton>
  <FaUpload />
</UploadFileButton>

// Works
<UploadFileButton>
  <FaUpload />
  <FaUpload />
</UploadFileButton>
```

I get this error message:

> Text in JSX has the type 'string', but the expected type of 'children'
>   is 'string | Element | Element[]

Which I suppose is because Typescript expects one of the types, but not more than one type at the time.

How can I specify an optional string and/or optional JSX.Elements as a type (if that makes any sense)?

I could bail out and go with `any`, but I want to know the correct typing for this scenario.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use React.ReactNode for typing the children array, why are you defining your own?

```
interface IUploadFileButtonProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about ReadNode. But I get ```Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'ReadNode'``` trying to use it as a type

Comment: which version of @types/react are you using?

Comment: "@types/react": "^16.9.23"

Comment: @mottosson so sorry, I had a typo in my answer I only noticed now.

Comment: Ah, great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can add `(string | JSX.Element)[]` to your type definition.

```
interface IUploadFileButtonProps {
  children: string | JSX.Element | JSX.Element[] | (string | JSX.Element)[];
}
```

Comment: Not the correct answer, but still, good to know it's possible to combine types like that. Thanks!